# Detect if GPS is activated in titanium studio

Tags: android, ios, gps, geolocation, titanium

How can I detect if the GPS is activated in Android and IOS?

```
if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled == false) 
{

}
```

I have tried this but on Android is returns always tru, and on IOS it seams to doe nothing.

How can I detect the GPS status in titanium for android and IOS?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS GPS permission is asked from the user when application starts. You can add this following code ti.xml and GPS is enabled for you in iOS until user explicitly disable this permission from settings.
Here is the code to add in ti.xml

```
 <ti:app>
    <ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
                <string>
                    Specify the reason for accessing the user's location information.
                    This appears in the alert dialog when asking the user for permission to
                    access their location.
                </string>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
</ti:app>
```